# AHK Want to type number and have text expand around it so I can change number but text remains

Tags: autohotkey

I want to accomplish the following.

I want to write 2450 ddu1, where 2450 = the number and ddu1 = the trigger.

Writing the above would make it look like this:

Door delivery SEK 2450, based on your specified weight measurements.

The thing is that the numbers vary and so I need to be able to write the correct number and then the "text expansion phrase" to trigger the text.

I can expand text but I can't do it with my number remaining in the middle of the expanded text.

Thank you kindly for your help and effort.

Answer (score 1):

There's no native support for dynamic hotstrings in AHK. But there's a great library that should fit your needs.

Check out [Hotstrings, by Menixator](https://github.com/Menixator/ahk-repo/tree/master/Hotstring).

Download that lib and try running this code:

```
#include Hotstring.ahk

; Listens for 1 or more digits, followed by "ddu1"
Hotstring("(\d+)\s+ddu1", "printPrice", 3)
return

; Prints a string with the digit in it
printPrice(param){
    str_s := "Door delivery SEK "
    str_e := ", based on your specified weight measurements."
    out_s := str_s . param.value(1) . str_e
    SendInput, %out_s%
}

Esc::ExitApp
```

It's triggered by typing one or more digits, followed by a space, followed by ddu1.

For example: `1 ddu1`, `512 ddu1`, `23123516161612 ddu1`.